# Select case ALL when grouping in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to select where the case is all data in the column meet the conditions as stated in the pseudo code:

```
select 
    s.Id as Id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.IsArchived=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Days,
    ALL(CASE WHEN s.IsArchived=1) AS IsArchived, -- Pseudo code
    sum(s.Price) as Price
from 
    Stuff s
join 
    Other o
on 
    s.FK_OtherId = o.Id
where 
    sl.Derp is not null 
group by
    s.Derp
```

How would I write correct syntax for the IsArchived column to aggregate the value 1 if all the data returns IsArchived=1 otherwise 0?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by _All_. Please clarify

Comment: Sorry if I´m not being clear enough.  This is kind of a silly question but what I meant is where all the data in the grouped column meet the conditions as IsArchived=1.  It looks like @TimoSta came with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `MIN()`:

```
SELECT ...
    MIN(s.IsArchived) as IsArchived,
    ...
FROM ...
```

Assuming that `s.IsArchived` is always either 0 or 1, it will return 0 if at least one of the rows contains the value 0 in this column, otherwise 1.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.  Yes, I didn´t say in the question but the value is always 0 or 1, therefore the min() function is the perfect solution for me.